# Initializing simple structs using initializer lists with clang

Tags: c++, types, initialization, clang

```
struct E_Point {
  double x, y;
  E_Point(): x(0), y(0) {}
  E_Point(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};

E_Point problem[] = { 
  {0.3871953044519425, -0.91857980824611341}, // Error: initialization of non-aggregate type 'E_Point' with an initializer list
  {0.36139704793723609, 0.91605957361605106}, 
  {-0.8208980020500205, 0.52853407296583088}, 
  {0.36178501611208552, 0.88880385168617226}, 
  {-0.43211245441046209, 0.6803420222771047} 
};
```

Compiling with `clang` 3.1.

I should point out that this compiles on GCC 4.6.1.

My current understanding is that `problem` is a non-aggregate type because it is an array of structs, making it compound and not just simply either a struct or array.

But sending the `-std=c++11` flag to `clang` does not alleviate the problem.

Update: Okay. Looks like my version of `clang` is somehow flawed and can't handle this for whatever reason.

What's a more traditional way to init? Do I do it this way? This compiles, but does it produce the same code? Will it call the ctor while the original doesn't?

```
E_Point problem[] = {
    E_Point(0.3871953044519425, -0.91857980824611341), // 1559
    E_Point(0.36139704793723609, 0.91605957361605106), // 1560
    E_Point(-0.8208980020500205, 0.52853407296583088), // 1798
    E_Point(0.36178501611208552, 0.88880385168617226), // 1799
    E_Point(-0.43211245441046209, 0.6803420222771047) // 1800
};
```

Comment: Time to switch the compiler? [Compiles file with gcc 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/z00cC)

Comment: Well, I want to see if clang has a flag to allow compiling this, or an explanation of why clang does not support initializer lists of non-aggregate types. I can surely make the initialization slightly more verbose so it will compile fine but that isn't getting to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: Yes it does have a [additional flag](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx11) perhaps you have not enabled it, something like `clang++ -std=c++11 [files]`, By default clang does not enable c++11 features, You have to enable explicitly.

Comment: @Als, I tried adding `-std=c++11` and also tried `-std=gnu++11`, did not fix issue.

Comment: Are you using apple's version of clang? This code compiles with my version of clang 3.1. Please post the full version (`clang++ --version`).

Comment: @JesseGood Interesting. Yes I'm trying to get my code compiled on OSX 10.7.4. Does your `clang` accept it without `-std=c++11`?

Comment: You could probably check if `__has_feature(cxx_generalized_initializers)` returns a true to check if the feature is available and enabled.

Comment: @Als: That isn't a C++11 feature; this is basic C++98 stuff. That's pure aggregate initialization, and it ought to work.

Comment: @JesseGood $ clang++ --version
Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, true and moreso because gcc 4.3.4 compiles it nice and clean,just a little confused with clang behavior(I don't use it much)so just checking out.

Comment: @StevenLu: Yes, my version (`clang version 3.1 (trunk) (llvm/trunk 155821)`) accepts the code without `-std=c++11`. I'm assuming it's a bug in your compiler.

Comment: BTW, your understanding is incorrect, an array of aggregates is an aggregate itself. The code is correct as is and it compiles with clang++ 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.54) [MacOX Lion]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks for pointing that out. This is quite strange.

Comment: Updated question with a few small additional questions.

Comment: @StevenLu: Could you post the exact code which gave you the compile error?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I assure you I did not *mean* to lie. The fact remains I have a bunch of code which compiles on `g++` and does not on `clang++`. Let me sort this out... Here's what i've got so far in terms of isolating this error. http://ideone.com/uvHZA Also, updated OP. And point taken; in the future I will make sure to test my code snippets before posting.

Comment: @StevenLu: Your `struct` that in the question here is an *aggregate* in your real code is **not** an aggregate. Everything else in the question is just a lost of time, as it is based on the premise that the original type is what it is not. `E_Point` is **not** an aggregate, you cannot use *aggregate initialization*. If you are using a C++11 compiler things change, as *uniform initialization* can be used there, and the inner curly braces `{}` will be mapped to a call to the constructor. What exact version of clang++ are you using?

Comment: output of `clang --version` is this: `Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58) (based on LLVM 3.1svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0 Thread model: posix`. Is it that once the struct gets a user-defined ctor it loses aggregateness? Shouldn't c++11 flag support that though?

Comment: @StevenLu: Uniform initializers were added late in the clang 3.1 process, the clang version that ships with Xcode 4 seems not to support this form of initialization, even if the official clang++3.1 release does support it. Note that I have had Apple clang 3.1 for a few months, but clang 3.1 was just released in the last two weeks...

Comment: Could somebody take a look at my ideone program? I'm quite confused... http://ideone.com/uvHZA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug in clang++:

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12670

In your case you can just use the explicit call to the constructor, as you provide in the last code snippet. As of whether the semantics are really the same (*will it generate the same code*), in most cases it will.

The case where the different syntax will lead to different behavior is when the type being constructed has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list<>`, in which case the *brace-initializer* will construct that initializer list. If the type does not have such a constructor, as is your case, the *brace-initializer* will call the appropriate constructor.